# Renaming Bulk files and changing certain prefix and raring them

Tags: linux, macos, bash, unix

I am using bash for renaming multiple script but it doesn't seem to work 
 here is the sample filename i want to rename Continuum  S02E13 [Number1Music.Us].mkv
output Continuum  S02E13 [bulkseries.com].mkv

```
for i in *.mkv;do mv $i ${i//[Number1Music.Us].mkv/[bulkseries.com.mkv]};done
```

and other question is to rar these files i havent tested it but it must be something like this.

```
for i in *.mkv;do rar a -m0 "$i.rar" "$i";done
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `[` and `]` since these are special symbols in glob pattern. Use this `mv` command:

```
for i in *.mkv;do
   mv "$i" "${i//\[Number1Music.Us\]/[bulkseries.com]}"
done
```

Comment: can you tell me exactly what do "" means i.e "$i" why we dont just use $i instead

Comment: In shell scripting it is always safer to quote the variable otherwise shell might expand them.